# Liquibase on MySQL does not respect int precision

Tags: mysql, liquibase, sqldatatypes

I am  using Liquibase 3.3.0 on MySQL.
My changelog have two changesets:

```
<changeSet author="robson" id="913-01">
    <createTable schemaName="${schema}" tableName="cte_cce">
        <column name="id" type="int(10)" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="company_code_nr" type="int(6)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="cte_code_nr" type="int(9)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="cte_invoice_nr" type="int(11)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="order" type="int(10)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addPrimaryKey schemaName="${schema}" 
                   constraintName="pk_cte_cce"
                   tableName="cte_cce"
                   columnNames="id"/>
</changeSet>
...
<changeSet author="robson" id="913-04">
    <addColumn schemaName="${schema}" tableName="cte_cce">
        <column name="sent" type="int(1)"/>
        <column name="last_return" type="varchar(500)"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Even specifing the size of int, all int are created with int(11).

This is breaking creation of foreign key for legacy tables.

There is some way to do Liquibase respect size set?

Comment: It should be like that only. if you need int(3) then use tinyint. Mentioning  precision in the data type would be a problem while moving from mysql to postgres .

@Nathan correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2282 to track the fix. For now, the best approach may be to use <modifySql> to fix the generated SQL. Or just use <sql>.